# OpenGL 2d Game Rendering layers using Z coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm in the process of converting the rendering of my top down 2d game from the SDL2 draw functions to direct OpenGL, so that I can take advantage of batch rendering and shaders.

Currently for drawing my various sprites, I use an array of layers, each layer has an array of gameObjects. I simply loop through the layers and all gameObjects in each layer when rendering so that stuff is drawn in the right order.i.e. layer 0 is background objects, layer 1 is main level , and layer 2 is foreground.

I'm realizing while designing the OpenGL code, that I now have the option to draw on the Z axis. So, I'm wondering - does it make sense for me to get rid of my layer arrays and simply have each gameObject have a layer value that I can simply use to represent a particular Z axis value. I could have Z axis 3,2 and 1, and just let the openGL draw calls handle what goes on top or in front of what.

Some of my textures WILL have transparent parts, so I'll need that to work as well.

Comment: If the transparency is only full transparent or not transparent, then it doesn't really matter which approach you choose. If you have semi transparent objects, you have to render back-to-front anyway.

Comment: Thanks, so if I DO have semi transparent textures, do I have to just make sure they are in the vertex buffer in the proper order when batching objects  OR does that mean I have to have a completely separate Draw call (separate batch) for the objects?